# How to override and inherit the extension in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-extensions

I'm new to iOS development and have read articles about the extension. But I couldn't find any examples about extending and inheriting from an extension.

Take [SpreadsheetView](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/SpreadsheetView) as an example. I want to override the [extension SpreadsheetView](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/SpreadsheetView/blob/master/Framework/Sources/SpreadsheetView%2BUIScrollViewDelegate.swift#L12).

I found that I able to override it by creating another extension in my own .swift file:

```
extension SpreadsheetView {
    public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // custom code
    }
}
```

However, I want to keep the default implementation also. How can I calling it from my custom function? `super.scrollViewDidScroll` or `(self as SpreadsheetView).scrollViewDidScroll` does not work.

and when I back to basic and copy all code over. It didn't allow. So that it's not an option to me:

> 'rowHeaderView' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Answer (score 1):

You can't override any implementation in extension. Extensions are used to add new functionality to an existing class, structure, enumeration, or protocol type.

If you want to override any function you should override the class and then override the method. Something like this.

```
class MySpreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView {
    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        super.scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView)
        //....
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it before and I got error `Cannot inherit from non-open class 'SpreadsheetView' outside of its defining module`. Does it mean I cannot subclass this lib? and must modify the lib directly?

Comment: In Swift class has to be `open`, if you wan't it to override outside the module. `SpreadsheetView` must be public or private that way you can't override it outside the module.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean to modify the module source is the only way? or any other elegant to handle this cause usually? (So if it's closed source code, you can't change it directly)

Comment: I think thats the only option. You can fork the GitHub repo and modify the source.  And if you are using cocoa-pods you can point `SpreadsheetView` to that branch.

Comment: that works: extension UITableView {
    override open func scrollRectToVisible(_ rect: CGRect, animated: Bool) {
        print("scroll to visible")
    }
} so it's possible BUT it overrides it for the whole project... which is not really what you want anyway. Just know that it's possible to override through extension.